# How can I configure gRPC options (like MaxReceiveMessageSize) when using .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, grpc, grpc-c#

I have a .NET Framework 4.7.2 Web App that uses a 3rd party client library to call the gRPC endpoint of a database.

The client library itself ([Dgraph-dotnet](https://github.com/MichaelJCompton/Dgraph-dotnet)) makes use of the [gRPC Core library](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/csharp)

A small number of responses from the database are greater than 4MB, which exceeds the default maximum received message size for gRPC.

If I were using .NET Core, I think this would be trivial to configure, e.g.

```
services.AddGrpc(options =>
{
    options.MaxReceiveMessageSize = 16 * 1024 * 1024; // 16 MB
});
```

I recall making message size configuration changes for WCF in the past in the web.config, e.g.:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Binding1" maxReceivedMessageSize = "16000000">
           ...
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Is there anything similar I can do configure the message size for gRPC when using .NET Framework?

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to create ChannelOptions and used them when server is created.

```
var channelOptions = new List<ChannelOption>();
channelOptions.Add(new ChannelOption("grpc.max_receive_message_length",16000000));

var server = new Grpc.Core.Server(channelOptions)
{
  Services = ...
  Ports = ...
}
server.Start();
```

Comment: There is also a list of predefined options, so you don't have to type the string manually.  
`Grpc.Core.ChannelOptions.MaxReceiveMessageLength `

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `HostBuilder` for example in an ASP.NET Core project you could configure the following in your `Program.cs`:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) 
  => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
         .ConfigureSerilog()
         .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
         {
             webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
             webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
             {
                 var http2 = options.Limits.Http2;
                 http2.InitialConnectionWindowSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 2; // 2 MB
                 http2.InitialStreamWindowSize = 1024 * 1024; // 1 MB
             });
         });
```